# Simple libxml2 XML parsing example with Obj-C, Xcode and libxml2?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, sax, libxml2

Could somebody give me an example of parsing a XML file using libxml2 please ?

```
<item>
    <title>Turtle</title>
    <type>Reptile</type>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Dog</title>
    <type>Mammal</type>
</item>
```

I spent a lot of time looking for a solution but I couldn't find it. I've successfully  added the framework and the header to the source path though.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Are you strictly bounded to libxml2? Have you tried GDataXML far more simpler